# OpenVPN server routing for client-web-traffic through VPN

Tags: openvpn, debian-jessie

I have set up OpenVPN server and client as described in the [official how to](https://openvpn.net/index.php/open-source/documentation/howto.html), using routing/tun devices. Point to point connection works. The client correctly routes all traffic into the VPN. Nothing comes back even though I did

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 10.8.0.0/24 -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
```

on the server like instructed in the how to. What is the problem?

Answer (score 1):

The how to doesn't mention one additional required step on the server, but a [FAQ entry](https://community.openvpn.net/openvpn/wiki/265-how-do-i-enable-ip-forwarding) does. In addition,

```
echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
```

is needed to make it work. To make this permanent, add

```
net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1
```

to `/etc/sysctl.conf`.

To verify that this worked, run

```
sysctl net.ipv4.ip_forward
```

. If this does not return `net.ipv4.ip_forward=1` then there is a problem.